# Is it possible to maintain metadata of drop off library in SharePoint 2013

Tags: drop-off-library

When routing a document using organizing rules of drop off library, the file metadata(created , created by, modified,modified by) are changed. Is it possible to move the document without changing metadata ?

Answer (score 1):

No. You will need to implement a custom router to make this available. See this basic example on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.recordsmanagement.recordsrepository.ecmdocumentrouter.aspx)